# How to get ElasticSearch to return scores independent of case?

Tags: elasticsearch, case-sensitive, tire

I would like ElasticSearch to return result scores that are independent of case. As an example, suppose I query for the string "HOUSE" or ("house") I obtain the following results:

`"House" => score: 0.6868894,
"House on the hill" => score: 0.52345484
"HOUSE" => score: 0.52200186`

In an ideal world, both "House" and "HOUSE" would have a score of 1.0 and "House on the hill" a score of 0.5.

So far I've tried adding a [custom analyser](https://gist.github.com/kimchy/1403902) and am now looking at the [omit_norms](https://gist.github.com/clintongormley/1868139) option. I'm also considering patterns since they have a [CASE_INSENSITIVE](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-analyzer.html) flag. Unfortunately I'm finding the official documentation lacks examples and code snippets...

Can anyone provide code snippets/examples of a query including the parameters required to achieve scores independent of case? Extra recognition to anyone who can provide a solution using Tire for Rails.

MAPPING
    `mapping _source: {} do
        indexes :id, type: 'integer'
        indexes :value, :analyzer => 'string_lowercase'
    end`

** analyser is custom analyser mentioned above

QUERY
    `{
        "query": {
            "filtered": {
                "query": {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "house"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "fields": ["value"],
        "from": 0,
        "size": 50,
        "sort": {
            "_score": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        },
        "explain": true
    }`

ElasticSearch 0.90.5; 
Rails 4.0.0; 
Tire (gem) 0.6.0

Comment: The case-sensitiveness doesn't have anything to do with your issue, and depends on how you analyzed your data. If you use the es defaults, everything is lowercased, thus the score difference is caused by something else, have a look at the explain output to know more.

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, the problem is caused by ES using many (5 by default) shards to score the documents and each shard uses only the documents that were allocated to it to compute its scores. Since I'm using test data and my DB is practically empty the score were completely off. Answer is to use [dfs_query_then_fetch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/understanding-query-then-fetch-vs-dfs-query-then-fetch/) search type (at least while developping..). Still searching for how to implement in Rails/Tire or set as default in ES.

Cheers,
nic

Comment: I understand what your problem was but I think it wasn't probperly described in your question, that's why your question and answer don't have anything to do with each other. Maybe you could improve your question and elaborate on your issue, which would definitely lead to your answer.